# insert text into textarea when option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help.
I'm trying to insert some text into a textarea-element when the url contains 'number' and an option with value='option2' of a selectbox is selected.

`var contentToInsert = 'Text';
if (location.href.indexOf("/number")) {
  if (value of selectbox == 'option2') {
    $("textarea").append(contentToInsert);
  }
}`

How do I check when the option is selected?
The text to insert shouldn't be shown when another option is selected.
So this would mean that I need on event-handler like onchange.

Have you got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event exists :

**Description:** *Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.*

Thy with something like that :

http://jsfiddle.net/J4Rkt/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this line of your code is right?

```
$("textarea").append(contentToInsert);
```

If you are referring to a tag with the id "textarea" then maybe it should be:

```
$("#textarea").append(contentToInsert);
```

Not to mention this will append to that id tag a child node.

Hope it helps :) Cheers!

Comment: Hi, well. I can use both. The id and the element. Thank you for the note.

Comment: Ah ... I see you're using the tag itself. Hm ... does it work already?

Comment: It works but all the textarea will be filled with the value of contentToInsert.