# functionality changes after inserting text to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

my questions arises from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962094/insert-text-into-textarea-when-option-selected).
I'm stumped and have been trying it for hours.
[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Rkt/2/) shows a text which is inserted to a textarea when one of the options is chosen.

By typing some words in the textarea the text of the textarea will not change when I choose another option. That's ok. But when I delete the words the whole functionality is lost somehow.

If it helps you to understand what I mean and want I'll write a small 'testplan' because I'm absolutely stumped:

1. Open [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Rkt/2/)
2. Type 'A' after 'Text' in the textarea.
3. Select option 2
   ->'TextA' stays in the textarea
4. Now delete 'TextA'
5. Select option1
   -> as you can see the textarea stays empty though I selected option 1

How can I prevent from this behaviour?
The added words to the textarea shall stay all the time. But if thereis no addition, the behavior shall not change.

Have you got an idea?

Comment: your jsfiddle works as expected in google chrome

Comment: I tested it in Chrome. 'TextA' disappears when selecting option 2. That's weird. I want it to stay. It stays in FF.

Comment: Have you tried this in a standalone HTML file? I'm looking at this in FF and something looks broken, but it could be with Fiddle

Comment: Hi, I tried it in this fiddle and via Greasemonkey. If I had an idea I would share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`html()` is the wrong way to set the contents of a textarea. Use `val()` instead.

The reason for this is that a textarea gets its initial value from the text contained between its start and end tags. Its current value is always stored in its `value` property. Changing the textarea's child nodes using `innerHTML` (which is what jQuery's `html()` method does) works initially, but once the `value` property has been changed (either by script or by the user editing the textarea content), the link between the textarea's child nodes and its value is broken.

Here's an updated version of your jsFiddle using `val()` instead of `html()`: http://jsfiddle.net/J4Rkt/5/

Bottom line: never use `html()` to get the current value of a textarea.